# Align dots in TOC to the right

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook

I am using the `amsbook.cls' file together with the command

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{amsbook}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SkipTocEntry}[4]{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Dotfill{\leavevmode\cleaders\hb@xt@.59em{\hss.\hss}\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother
...
```

to create dots within the sections level of the table of contents (TOC). The `amsbook.cls' file is modified accordingly with (please note the comments)

```
\def\@toclevel{0}
\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\relax
\ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth
\else
\par \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{#2}%
\begingroup \hyphenpenalty\@M
\@ifempty{#4}{%
  \@tempdima\csname r@tocindent\number#1\endcsname\relax
}{%
  \@tempdima#4\relax
}%
\parindent\z@ \leftskip#3\relax \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\relax
\rightskip\@pnumwidth plus4em \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
#5\leavevmode\hskip-\@tempdima #6\nobreak\relax
% \hfil\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{#7}}\par % <-- we commented this line out
\ifnum#1<\c@tocdepth\hfill\else\Dotfill\fi\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{#7}}\par % <-- and, instead, use this line to allow for dots in the TOC
\nobreak
\endgroup
\fi}
```

However, the dots are aligned to the left rather than to the right (see the picture below). How do I align the dots on the right side next to page numbers?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: it always helps if you provide a test file, but try `\leaders` the dots will then all be lined up.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\cleaders` makes unaligned, centred dots. If you use `\leaders` (or the standard latex `\@dottedtocline`) the dots on each line will be at the same horizontal positions as the other lines